# Mocking a method which calls another method

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Suppose I have a test class TestSuite with a method `test_database_inaccessible()`.  I want to test a method `run()` in another class, `AA_database.run()` calls  `is_primary()`.  I can mock is_primary to return True.

I have tried

```py
 with patch.object(AADatabase, "is_primary") as is_primary_mocked:
     self.dbsize = 2.1e10
     self.returncode = 2
     is_primary_mocked.return_value = True
     self.AADatabase.run()
```

but I get

> AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'AADatabase'

Previously, I had tried simply

```
 with patch.object(AADatabase, "is_primary") as is_primary_mocked:
        self.dbsize = 2.1e10
        self.returncode = 2
        is_primary_mocked.return_value = True
        AADatabase.run()
```

But I got a different error message then.

If patch is the wrong tool here, I don't mind switching to a different one.  I have tried quite a few different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution based on the code you provided.

`main.py`:

```py
class AADatabase:
    @classmethod
    def is_primary(cls):
        return False

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        return cls.is_primary()
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from main import AADatabase
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestAADatabase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_database_inaccessible(self):
        with patch.object(AADatabase, 'is_primary') as is_primary_mocked:
            is_primary_mocked.return_value = True
            res = AADatabase.run()
            self.assertTrue(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/58862981/main.py            5      1    80%   4
src/stackoverflow/58862981/test_main.py      11      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        16      1    94%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58862981